# PaypalFunctions Java

Tags: java, paypal

I'm using Paypal Express Checkout from my Spring MVC application (but for now testing with a Servlet). I'm using the PaypalFunctions.java file for making transaction. Right now I'm testing on sandbox.

I created an account on Paypal from API access, I created my API username, password and signature. I inserted that in my PaypalFunctions file.

Now when I'm connecting with it to Paypal, it says **Security Header Is Not Valid**. I've gone through various websites & found that it is for incorrect username/password type of issue. They said that I have to use different account for SandBox.

I don't understand how to use a different account for sandbox; do I have to generate a different API username/password/signature for SandBox? I don't find any other account information in the whole code.

Here is my code:

```
gv_APIUserName = "<username>";
gv_APIPassword = "<password>";
gv_APISignature = "<signature>";

boolean bSandbox = true;

/*
Servers for NVP API
Sandbox: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
Live: https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
*/

/*
Redirect URLs for PayPal Login Screen
Sandbox: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=XXXX
Live: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=XXXX
*/

if (bSandbox == true)
{
    gv_APIEndpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";
    PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
}
else
{
    gv_APIEndpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
    PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out :)

In paypal sandbox, i had to create a business account, then click profile, then API credentials

Hope this answer will help others